# I have upvoted answer without points. What does it mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I have got votes on several questions but I haven't got points for this ones. Are there any restrictions?
For example, [RecursiveDirectoryIterator to only scan 1 level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210849/recursivedirectoryiterator-to-only-scan-1-level/7210865#7210865)

In this question I have got 5 upvotes but get only 15 points for the best answer instead of 65.

Comment: Looks like you hit the reputation cap yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cap of 200 points per day for upvotes.

But you get points of reps for accepteds without reps cap.